# java repeat character

Tags: java, string, for-loop, printf

I am a java beginner, please keep that in mind. I have to make a program that reads a number, and then displays that amount of exclamation mark "!".

This is what i have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;

class E_HerhaalKarakter1 {

 PrintStream out;

 E_HerhaalKarakter1 () {
  out = new PrintStream(System.out);
 }

 String printUitroeptekens (int aantal) {
  String output = "!"

  for (int i = 0; i <= aantal; i++) {
   output.concat("!");
  }
  return output;
 }

 void start () {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  out.printf("Hoeveel uitroeptekens wilt u weergeven?\n");

  if(in.hasNext()) {
   out.printf("baldbla");
   printUitroeptekens(in.nextInt());
   out.printf("%s",output);
  }
 }

 public static void main (String[] argv) {
  new E_HerhaalKarakter1().start();
 }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please use English (even in code) when asking questions on an English forum.

Comment: Indeed keep at least the entire code English (all identifiers; classnames, methodnames, variablenames). Messages can be kept in Dutch, but preferably add an English comment to make it clear.

Answer (score 23):

If you do actually have the requirement to create a string which contains X number of exclamation marks, then here's a way to do it without repeated concatenation:

```
char[] exmarks = new char[aantal];
Arrays.fill(exmarks, '!');
String exmarksString = new String(exmarks);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your program doesn't work because String.concat() does not change the string, but returns a *new* string. For example, "a".concat("b") is "ab". So, you should write `output = output.concat("!")` instead of `output.concat("!")`.

However, this will be very inefficient because building up a string of n exclamation marks will take O(n^2) time (look up "big oh notation" on google or wikipedia, see also [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)).

Look at the documentation to the `StringBuilder` class and use it. It was designed for building up strings from parts.

Comment: If efficiency is a concern, then you should definitely note that any kind of concatenation is unnecessary to solve this problem. Only Omega(lg n) memory is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are very close, Tom.

First, the normal way to build up a `String` in Java is with the `StringBuilder` class, like this:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(aantal);
while (aantal-- > 0)
  buf.append('!');
return buf.toString();
```

Then, you need to declare a variable named `output` in the scope of the `start()` method, and assign the result of the `printUitroeptekens()` method to that variable, like this:

```
String output = printUitroeptekens(in.nextInt());
out.printf("%s%n", output);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your program should have this structure:

```
read number x 
repeat this x times  
  print '!'
```

There's nothing in the statement requiring you to actually build a string as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is probably a **simplified** example for us to understand the problem. The real problem is likely be a lot more complicated.