# Iteration Structures

Tags: php, for-loop

Our teacher in PHP is asking us to create a program where we would print a pyramid like figure, but what I'm really confused about is how do I print those asterisk by using loop or for. the other thing is how do i generate new size, by new size I mean for example:

the first figure would be 5x5, then if i refresh a page it would generate a new size like 11x11 or 7x7

if anyone would be be able to answer my question, i would be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried something yet? perhaps we can help you with your code.

Comment: to be honest, i dont have any ideas about what to do, our teacher didn't give that much information, only a image of what it should look like, but sadly i can't post that image here since my reputation is low.

Answer (score 0):

I [posted an answer very similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932962/how-can-i-print-a-triangle-with-s-using-for-loop-in-java/10933101#10933101) already for Java. In PHP, the code is very similar:

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        for($j=0; $j<=$i; $j++)
        {
            echo "*";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
?>
```

This will create a right triangle. If you want a pyramid, you should only slightly have to modify it, but I'll leave that part to you so I don't rob you of the learning experience.