# What is the java equivalent of pythonic "a" * 10?

Tags: java

I want to build a string which contains the number of "a" based on the a runtime variable i.For example if the value of i is 3 value of string would be "aaa" if the value of i is 5 string would be "aaaaa".how can i create it in java [ without the obvious way of creating a stringbuffer in a loop] for example in python i can just do `string = 'a' * i`.

Comment: There is no such shortcut in Java.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255500/can-i-multiply-strings-in-java-to-repeat-sequences

Comment: Also possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306235/java-repeat-character which seems to provide an answer closer to what this user is asking.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) we can do his with [repeat](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method:

> public static String repeat(String string,int count)
>
> Returns a string consisting of a specific number of concatenated
>   copies of an input string. For example, repeat("hey", 3) returns the
>   string "heyheyhey".

Comment: I guess they too use StringBuffer in a for loop internally

Answer (score 1):

```
char [] a = new char[5];
Arrays.fill(a, 'f');
```